# Survdiff (package survival) with frequency weights (obtained after Coarsened Exact Matching - package matchit)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weighted

I am doing a counterfactual impact evaluation on survival data. More precisely, I try to evaluate the impact of vocational training on time spent in unemployment. I use the Kaplan Meier estimator of the survival curve (package survival).

Before doing Kaplan Meier, I use coarsened exact matching (aim is ATT) to get the control and treatment groups close in terms of pretreatment covariates (package MatchIt).

For the Kaplan Meier estimator, I have to use the weights form the matching, which works well using the weights option and robust standard errors of survfit :

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

kp_cem <- survfit(Surv(time=time_cem,event=status_cem)~treatment_cem, data=data_impact_cem,robust =TRUE,weights =weights)
```

Although, when I try to use a log-rank test to test for the difference in survival curves between treatment and control groups, I cannot take into account the frequency weights from the matching so the test statistics are not correct.

```
log_rank <- survdiff(Surv(time=time_cem,event=status_cem)~treatment_cem, data=data_impact_cem,rho=0)
```

I tried the option "pval = TRUE" of ggsurvplot (package survminer) but the problem is the same, the frequency weights are not taken into account.

How can I include frequency weights in survdiff? Are there other packages to compute log-rank test taking into account frequency weights (obtained after matching)?

Comment: There is a `survey::svylogrank` function. Seems like that ought to do what is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this:

First, you can use the `survey::svylogrank` function, as @IRTFM suggests. This will treat the weights as sampling weights, but I think that's ok with the robust standard errors that `svylogrank` uses.

Second, you can use `survival::coxph`. The logrank test is the score test in a Cox model, and `coxph` takes frequency weights. Use `robust=TRUE` if you want a robust score test: it will be at the bottom of the output of `summary(your_cox_model)` and you can extract it as `summary(your_cox_model)$robscore`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much @Thomas Lumley and @IRTFM for your answers.
Here is how I apply your 2 suggestions (I added some comments + references).

**1. Using survey::svylogrank**

I don’t feel very confortable using sampling weights while it is really frequency weights that I have.

How should I specify the survey design ? The weights come from Coarsened Exact Matching (matchit with method = "cem") which is a class of stratum matching.
Should I specify the strata and the weights in the survey design ? In this vignette form Matchit [Estimating Effects After Matching](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#after-stratum-matching), it is suggested to use only weights and robust standard errors in the survival analysis (not the strata) (p. 27).

Here is how I specify the design and how I obtain the log-rank test using the package survey taking into account the weights from matching :

```
library(survey)
design_weights <- svydesign(id=~ibis, strata=~subclass, weights=~weights, data=data_impact_cem)
log_rank <- svylogrank(Surv(time=time_cem,event=status_cem)~treatment_cem, design=design_weights, rho=0)
```

**2. Using survival::coxph**

Thank you for this piece of information, being quite new to survival analysis, I overlooked this nice property of the equivalency of score test from cox model and log-rank test. For people wishing more info on this subject, I found this book very instructive : Moore, D. (2016). Applied survival analysis using R. New York: NY : Springer (p 58).

I find this 2d option more attractive than the 1st involving survey. Here is how I apply it :

```
library(survival)
cox_cem <-coxph(Surv(time=time_cem,event=status_cem)~treatment_cem, data=data_impact_cem,robust =TRUE,weights =weights)
sum_cox_cem <-summary(cox_cem)
score_test <-sum_cox_month[[13]][[1]]
score_test <- round(score_test,3) 
pvalue <- sum_cox_month[[13]][[3]]
pvalue <-if(pvalue<0.001){"<0.001"} else{round(pvalue,3)}
```

Here is the difference between the 2 test statistics (quite close in the end).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydJvd.png)

Though, I still wonder why the weights option does not exist in survdiff.